# Kubernetes pod distribution amongst nodes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to make kubernetes distribute pods as much as possible?
I have "Requests" on all deployments and global Requests as well
as HPA. all nodes are the same.

Just had a situation where my ASG scaled down a node and one service became completely unavailable as all 4 pods were on the same node that was scaled down.

I would like to maintain a situation where each deployment must spread its containers on at least 2 nodes.

Answer (score 39):

Here I leverage [Anirudh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169994/1024794) adding example code.

My initial kubernetes [yaml](https://github.com/ypapax/say-grpc/blob/master/backend/kubernetes_external_ip.yaml) looked like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: say-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: say
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: say
        image: gcr.io/hazel-champion-200108/say
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: say-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: say
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.112
```

At this point, kubernetes scheduler somehow decides that all the 6 replicas should be deployed on the same node.

Then I [added](https://github.com/ypapax/say-grpc/commit/d035e9c2e8195996cfbb2df1af7ca66f4c6ba586) `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` to force the pods beeing deployed on different nodes:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: say-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: say
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: say
        image: gcr.io/hazel-champion-200108/say
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      affinity:
              podAntiAffinity:
                requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                  - labelSelector:
                      matchExpressions:
                        - key: "app"
                          operator: In
                          values:
                          - say
                    topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: say-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: say
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.112
```

Now all the pods are run on different nodes. And since I have 3 nodes and 6 pods, other 3 pods (6 minus 3) can't be running (pending). This is because I required it: `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide 

NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
say-deployment-8b46845d8-4zdw2   1/1       Running            0          24s       10.244.2.80   night
say-deployment-8b46845d8-699wg   0/1       Pending            0          24s       <none>        <none>
say-deployment-8b46845d8-7nvqp   1/1       Running            0          24s       10.244.1.72   gray
say-deployment-8b46845d8-bzw48   1/1       Running            0          24s       10.244.0.25   np3
say-deployment-8b46845d8-vwn8g   0/1       Pending            0          24s       <none>        <none>
say-deployment-8b46845d8-ws8lr   0/1       Pending            0          24s       <none>        <none>
```

Now if I [loosen](https://github.com/ypapax/say-grpc/commit/a37efdc26a1f610522990e1e9a77df7dc0b93fdd) this requirement with `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: say-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: say
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: say
        image: gcr.io/hazel-champion-200108/say
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      affinity:
              podAntiAffinity:
                preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                  - weight: 100
                    podAffinityTerm:
                      labelSelector:
                        matchExpressions:
                          - key: "app"
                            operator: In
                            values:
                            - say
                      topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: say-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: say
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.112
```

First 3 pods are deployed on 3 different nodes just like in the previous case. And the rest 3 (6 pods minus 3 nodes) are deployed on various nodes according to kubernetes internal considerations.

```
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
say-deployment-57cf5fb49b-26nvl   1/1       Running   0          59s       10.244.2.81   night
say-deployment-57cf5fb49b-2wnsc   1/1       Running   0          59s       10.244.0.27   np3
say-deployment-57cf5fb49b-6v24l   1/1       Running   0          59s       10.244.1.73   gray
say-deployment-57cf5fb49b-cxkbz   1/1       Running   0          59s       10.244.0.26   np3
say-deployment-57cf5fb49b-dxpcf   1/1       Running   0          59s       10.244.1.75   gray
say-deployment-57cf5fb49b-vv98p   1/1       Running   0          59s       10.244.1.74   gray
```

Comment: What if I only have one node available and rest two are full? will it deploy it all pods on one single node(in which case it is not fulfilling our requirement) or will spin up new nodes and deploy on different nodes?

Comment: @Maxin : Can you please check and anwer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718026/kubernetes-pod-distribution-amongst-nodes-with-preferred-mode

Comment: This answer has become outdated. The right answer for **k8s 1.19** is to use `topologySpreadConstraints` ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64958458/968003

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like what you want is [Inter-Pod Affinity and Pod Anti-affinity](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/#alpha-features-affinity-and-anti-affinity).

> Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity were introduced in Kubernetes
>   1.4. Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity allow you to constrain which nodes your pod is eligible to schedule on based on labels on pods that
>   are already running on the node rather than based on labels on nodes.
>   The rules are of the form “this pod should (or, in the case of
>   anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if that X is already running
>   one or more pods that meet rule Y.” Y is expressed as a LabelSelector
>   with an associated list of namespaces (or “all” namespaces); unlike
>   nodes, because pods are namespaced (and therefore the labels on pods
>   are implicitly namespaced), a label selector over pod labels must
>   specify which namespaces the selector should apply to. Conceptually X
>   is a topology domain like node, rack, cloud provider zone, cloud
>   provider region, etc. You express it using a topologyKey which is the
>   key for the node label that the system uses to denote such a topology
>   domain, e.g. see the label keys listed above in the section
>   “Interlude: built-in node labels.”

Anti-affinity can be used to ensure that you are spreading your pods across failure domains. You can state these rules as preferences, or as hard rules. In the latter case, if it is unable to satisfy your constraint, the pod would fail to get scheduled.

Comment: I guess this is more of kubernetes problem. The scheduler must be intelligent enough to spread the pods in such a way that it provides high availability, even in case of as node down. (Provided there is more than one node). Affinity works, but it is more of use when we want stateful containers to be scheduled in node that has SSD disk space. Just my thoughts, what do you guys think ?

Comment: That is not strictly true. A preferred affinity rule can specify relations between pods using labels, irrespective of whether they have attached storage.

Comment: I don't believe that this is the right approach, The fact that I want the pods to be spread doesn't mean that I don't want to have 2 on the same node. This solution is like telling me, Create a daemon set, that's not what I am looking for. or there's a way to make a such an intelligent pod affinity that will decide if there is enough availability in the deployment, to start sharing more of the same pod on the same node

Comment: @Gleeb, the affinity can be preferences or hard rules. If it's preferred, it will fall back to using the same node **if** it cannot find different nodes to schedule on.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out.

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan : Can you please check and see if you can answer this query of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718026/kubernetes-pod-distribution-amongst-nodes-with-preferred-mode