# what k8s take into account at the time to assing pods to a node?

Tags: kubernetes

maybe is a obvious question , but I have not found a documentation about how k8s is assigning pods to a node , currently I have a cluster with 5 worker nodes , and 3 nodes are full with pods , and the other 2 don't , I know that I can set cpu, mem in the yaml for each container , but by default how does k8s work on it?

Comment: See this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/ and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159843/kubernetes-pod-distribution-amongst-nodes

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) link provided by @Amityo, the main concept assigning Pods to the Nodes in Kubernetes based on usage `nodeSelector` and `Node affinity` model, however you might also take a look at "[Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)" representing quite similar approach but they allow Nodes to make decision whether Pods can be scheduled by matching some specific criteria with `key:`, `value:`, `effect:` toleration.