# Why are my pods not utilizing multiple nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Currently, I have 2 nodes on AWS

```
NAME                                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
NODE-1-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.cn-north-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   15d   v1.16.13-eks-2ba888
NODE-2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.cn-north-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   13d   v1.16.13-eks-2ba888
```

Here is also a screenshot of my CPU loads

**NODE 1**
[image: NODE !]

**NODE 2**
[image: NODE 2]

My problem is whenever I deploy my application to production I will max out my cpu usage on **NODE 2** and it will slow down the entire site

Here is my deployment config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend # name of the deployment
  namespace: backend
  labels: # these labels apply to the deployment
    app: root
    component: backend

spec:
  replicas: 2
  minReadySeconds: 20
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: root
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # these labels apply to our container
        app: root
        component: backend
        version: xxx_${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend # name of our container
        image: xxx/xxx_main:${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER} # the URI that we got from ECR
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: env
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000 # expose the running contianer on port 3000
          name: backend
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: backend
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 20

      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: xxx
```

Am I not scaling things out properly here? what is the point of having two nodes if only one is ever in use? How can i properly scale my applications to use multiple nodes?

Comment: You could use [node-anti affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) to distribute the replicas across nodes.

Comment: @Ralf that is a workaround to solve the problem, OP is interested in the reason for the problem itself.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia, that's why it's in a comment, not in an answer. Reason could be pods not being distributed, load balancing not set up correctly, client not targeting load balancer but pod, etc... But before you start investigating other issues, you should make sure the pods are actually deployed across the available nodes in a deterministic way.

Comment: possibly dupe; https://stackoverflow.com/q/39092090/92837 specifically: `Therefore, it's best to specify the service first, since that will ensure the scheduler can spread the pods associated with the service as they are created by the controller(s), such as Deployment`

Comment: @Ralf based on what you just said there I can indeed confirm that my backend-specific nodes are only being scheduled on one node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the node scheduling algorithm is based on priority score with different priority algorithms contributing to the score. One such priority algorithm is the `ImageLocalityPriority` which adds a positive priority score for nodes already having the images used by the pod. So initially, a node that already has the first replica of the pod running, gets a small priority bump due to the `ImageLocalityPriority`. Once more and more replicas are added, the number of pods running on each node even out because other priorities like `BalancedResourceAllocation` etc also take affect.

There is also a `SelectorSpreadPriority` which helps in minimising
the number of pods belonging to a same service on a node. So if you create your `service` object before creating the deployment, it might help.

To enforce the pods to spread out, you should add [inter-pod anti-affinity constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) to your pods.

You should also consider adding [requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) to your containers. This helps in spreading out the pods as the `LeastRequestedPriority` priority also kicks in. (**Note:** There is also `MostRequestedPriority` which adds priority for used nodes but it is not enabled by default).

Comment: Very well written answer this got me going in the right direction

Comment: In the end, it was because I wasn't setting resource limits which has helped tremendously and I would suggest anyone who stumbles upon this post to at least take a look into it