# HA Scheduler Strategy in Kubernetes (Evenly distribute pod replicas across machines)

Tags: kubernetes, docker-swarm

I wanted to evenly distribute Kubernetes pod replicas in the cluster.

Let's assume I have 2 pods one is having 2 replicas(light weight) and other is having 3 replicas(heavy weight). Also let's assume I have 3 worker nodes in the cluster.

If I deploy the 1st pod with labels of 1st worker then both the 2 replicas will run in 1st worker.

Now if I run 2nd pod having 3 replicas then these should go to each machine (per machine one replica) instead of they going into other 2 machines by leaving the 1st machine. **If I have 6 replicas then 2 replicas should go to each machine**.

I wanted docker swarm scheduler behaviour like this here https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/308#issue-147931992.

Is it possible to achieve this in Kubernetes without moving to docker swarm?

Comment: There's some discussion of this in [How can I distribute a deployment across nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092090/how-can-i-distribute-a-deployment-across-nodes).  By default each pod will be scheduled on the least-busy node, without a lot of concern for which specific other pods are running on that node, but you could use an [anti-affinity policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) to encourage the pods to be spread around more.

Comment: I need to agree with David Maze comment. Also, have you seen following docs on [Pod topology spread](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)? I'd reckon you can also check the `kube-scheduler` (component responsible for assigning `Pods` to `Nodes`): https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/